# How to open a URL in default Web browser ?

Tags: c#

Lets say I want to open the Google.com in the default browser, then what would I type in there to make sure it always opens in the default browser ?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, Event Args e);
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `Process.Start()`, which can take an absolute URL (including protocol) and open it with the registered program.

Comment: It finds that there is an error on "start" as in "process.start" and im not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Aside from that it says "'System.Diagnostics' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'"

Answer (score 1):

Add `System.Diagnostics` namespace to you class and then you can use the method below;

`Process.Start(string URL);`

As you mentioned,to open Google in default browser use this;

`Process.Start("www.google.com");`

This will always open the URL in user's default browser.

**Update**

Conside you have a Button named `button1` and on its click you want to open `Google` in the default browser.Click event will look like the below by default.And then add the following code to the event handler;

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);
 {
      DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to open Google ?", "Someapp", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

      if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Process.Start("www.google.com");
        }

      else
        {
           //React as needed.
        }
 }
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain further? just like show me the exact code? I'm totally clueless.